# Paint images dynamically in a GridView

Tags: android, image, bitmap, baseadapter

I have this class that paints images in a GridView:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
   Context MyContext;
   Vector<User> users;
   int level;


   public ImageAdapter(Context _MyContext, Vector<User> _users, int _level)
   {
      MyContext = _MyContext;
      users = _users;
      level = _level;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() 
   {
                     /* Set the number of element we want on the grid */
       if(users==null)
           return 0;
      return users.size();
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
   {
      View MyView = convertView;            
                             /*we define the view that will display on the grid*/
         //Inflate the layout
         LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
         MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

         // Add The Text!!!
         TextView tv = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);

         // Add The Image!!!           
         ImageView iv = (ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
         iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_restricted);
         iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultperson02);
         byte[] bytes;
         if(position<users.size()){
             final User user =users.get(position);
            tv.setText(users.get(position).getDisplay_name());  
            bytes = user.getAvatar();
            if(bytes!=null && bytes.length>0 ){
                try{
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }catch(Exception e){                        

                }
            }

         }

      return MyView;
   }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This class usually works perfectly but sometimes I get this exception:

```
01-18 12:39:26.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30496): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 12:39:26.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30496): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=15303KB, Allocated=10747KB, Bitmap Size=18391KB)
01-18 12:39:26.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30496):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
01-18 12:39:26.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30496):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:625)
01-18 12:39:26.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30496):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:638)
```

I have tried recycling the bitmap but the error still appears.

Do you have any idea why I have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you must reuse the convertview class. What you are doing in the above code is creating a new view every-time getView is called. This isn't the correct way to do things. Instead check if convertview is null or not. If it's null then inflate the view else reuse the convertview. For more details check [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html).